# Only few of CSS & Images are not loading

Tags: php, css, image, internal-server-error

I have a big problem in website http://www.konasignature.com/. While load my website in browser some of CSS & Images are not loading and returning the "500 Internal server error". I can see that errors in chrome browser's resources list. But when i load that error css & images in new browser window its loading perfect without errors. Only its returning error when it loading for a php page inside.

Also some time "500 Internal server error" not showing for css or images which are return error before.

And when i check server logs am getting below error above 20 times on every refresh

[Wed Feb 01 00:05:15 2012] [error] [client 122.174.77.143] (12)Cannot allocate memory: couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/konasign/public_html/Rrrrr/core.php, referer: http://www.konasignature.com/

Comment: What do you get in the server's logs?

Comment: Unfortunately, an Internal Server Error is a generic server message that could essentially mean **anything**. Check your error log to see what specific error is being sent. Something is happening on the backend of your server, which probably won't have anything to do with PHP or CSS.

Comment: Am a developer. I don't have access to server logs. This is only the right way to fix this? Then i will try now by contacting the client & hosting team. Thanks for your replies sarnold & animuson.

Comment: Almost definitely a server configuration issue.

Comment: @sarnold hi i updated the server logs in my question.

Comment: Looks like the server is low on memory, perhaps due to many concurrent process images occupying the memory. Please refer to [this discussion](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=925866) for possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be running low on memory on the box and it is unable to spawn a new child process to serve the request. You can,

1. Increase the memory on the box
2. See what is eating up memory by running `top` command and debug.